# Set a default value for "number of items per page" in WooCommerce admin product list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

WordPress allows each user to set his own value for "Number of items per page" in the Admin Products Page `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product`.

I'm looking for a code to set the **same value** for "Number of items per page" for all users regardless of your user rol.

Is there a way to do this? Something like:

```php
add_action('admin_init', 'set_value_for_all_users');
function set_value_for_all_users() {
    // set $Number_of_items_per_page for all users = 20
    $Number_of_items_per_page = 20;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `wp_user_meta` table there is a meta key `edit_product_per_page` that sets this limit. By default 20.

However, to edit this setting for the admin product list you can use a filter hook from the `get_items_per_page()` WordPress function

[WP_List_Table::get_items_per_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/get_items_per_page/) - Gets the number of items to display on a single page.

```php
protected function get_items_per_page( $option, $default = 20 ) {
    $per_page = (int) get_user_option( $option );
    if ( empty( $per_page ) || $per_page < 1 ) {
        $per_page = $default;
    }
 
    /**
     * Filters the number of items to be displayed on each page of the list table.
     *
     * The dynamic hook name, `$option`, refers to the `per_page` option depending
     * on the type of list table in use. Possible filter names include:
     *
     *  - `edit_{$post_type}_per_page`
     *
     * @since 2.9.0
     *
     * @param int $per_page Number of items to be displayed. Default 20.
     */
    return (int) apply_filters( "{$option}", $per_page );
}
```

---

So to answer your question, change `{$post_type}` with `product`
and then you get:

```php
function filter_edit_product_per_page ( $per_page ) {
    // The number of items to be displayed on product page of the list table
    $per_page = 50;
    
    return $per_page;
}
add_filter( 'edit_product_per_page', 'filter_edit_product_per_page', 10, 1 );
```